# How to set Gmail as default email client in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, gmail, webmail

How can I use Gmail (in Chrome) as the default email handler in Windows 8?

I used to use GmailNotifier in Windows 7, but that doesn't seem to work anymore. Clicking on a mailto: link simply opens Chrome with a blank page.

I am not interested in using the Mail app built into Windows 8.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Open Gmail in Chrome. Then see this. Click on the eye in the address bar.

[image]

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work, even when clicking a `mailto` link within Chrome :(

Comment: @Leftium Can you see the options of screenshot? Have you selected `Use Gmail`? And, what's the version of your Chrome?

Comment: hmmm.. this seems to work, now. I'm not sure what changed since the last time I tried it~

Comment: Ah that's great!

Comment: I do not have the eye icon in chrome - does that come from installing an extension?

Comment: Not an extension. It is inbuilt into chrome. Search for handler settings in Chrome settings. You might have to switch it on

Comment: Directions should also point that user must click the "eye" icon on the address bar. (took me a good 5 minutes to find out)

Comment: @Entrodus Done. Added the additional instruction

Comment: These days it doesn't seem to look like an eye, more like two overlapping diamonds. On OS X anyway.

Comment: I don't have have that eye/overlapping-diamongs in my search bar.  I did go into Settings and set mailto: handler to gmail. Still no luck.

Answer (score 11):

1. Close Chrome
2. Open `C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State` with Notepad (or, any other text editor).
3. Locate `"javascript": true,` in `protocol_handler` section of the file, replace `true` with `false` and save the file.
   [image: Chrome State Settings]
4. Launch Chrome, visit Gmail and Sign in.
5. In address bar of same tab, type/paste this & hit enter: `javascript:navigator.registerProtocolHandler("mailto", "https://mail.google.com/mail/?extsrc=mailto&url=%s", "Gmail");`
6. [Optional] Close Chrome & revert back your changes in `Local State` file.
7. Open `Default Programs`.
   [image: Search for Default Programs]
8. Click `Associate a file type or protocol with a program`.
   [image: Default Programs dialogue]
9. Select `MAILTO` and then click `Change program...` button.
   [image: Set Associations]
10. Choose `Google Chrome` from the list.

Done!

Comment: This is fantastic! Can it be done with Firefox?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, but [it seems that it cannot be done in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/952585) (otherwise I'm missing something).

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps after installation of Gmail Client 
[image]
[image]
[image]

Change your Default Client to Gmail..

Hope this Helps...

Comment: There is no Gmail option!

Comment: @Leftium see my answer

Answer (score 0):

See the below link. It expands upon Sant14's answer by first having you create the necessary entry that would then show up in your 'Default Programs' > 'Programs' list.

http://www.groovypost.com/howto/change-windows-8-default-email-client/

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier solution.  The link below installs an applet which gives you the option as a check box, and you don't have to use Chrome.  I'm using Firefox because I have some sort of virus on Chrome that hijacks clicks and sends me to advertisements.

http://toolbar.google.com/gmail-helper/notifier_windows.html

Comment: This is no longer supported by google.