# Gmail as default client for Windows 7/Vista

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, email, gmail, scanning

I have to use old pc and can't change/upgrade it. It mostly using for scanning & emailing. We use Google apps for domain as a mail server. Can I somehow scan and email doc from this PC in one simple easy step (preferably as pdf)?

Default Windows "Fax and Scan" software allows send scanned doc as email only via local client (I know how to configure IMAP, but looking for other simpler solution).

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to set the default mail app to GMail like explained in this question ? http://superuser.com/questions/499349/how-to-set-gmail-as-default-email-client-in-windows-8

Comment: I use tvhgooglemapi to be able to send mails directly from Word (Send document as attachment), or Windows Explorer (Send To Mail Recipient). It can be downloaded here: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5rR8r10bVzvQklLN0cxMEFFWXM&usp=sharing#list . It does require a jre to be installed though.

Comment: @Berend I tried tvhgooglemapi. It doesn't allow me to authenticate user. Google propose decrease security level for using it which is not good IMHO.

Comment: @EricDarchis It's for Windows 8 and in Chrome. Not my case

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what kind of security are we talking about? I was asked only once for my Google login. TvhGoogleMapi then remembers this.

Comment: No ideas. The account I tried don't use 2 factor authentication. And yes, I checked both option (gmail and apps for domain). Auth was failed on both. By the way, which version of tvhgooglemapi are you using?

Comment: Maybe it just doesn't support 2 factor auth. I only enabled that recently and haven't used googlemapi after that. There's a similar application here, but I haven't tried it: http://www.gmailnotifier.com/

Comment: And did you try to generate an Application specific password? https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833

Comment: Yes. Now it works. Thank you. Besides, can TvhGoogleMapi cache (i.e. store) password?

Comment: @Berend, I think you got the right answer? May be good to move it to an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set GMail as the system's default MAPI mail application, download TvhGoogleMapi from this site: https://code.google.com/p/tvhgooglemapi/ and install it. Other similar applications such as GMailNotifier should also work, but I haven't tried.

Note that if you use Googles two step verification, you need to use an application specific password instead of your original password. This is desribed here: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833