# Make Win-Up maximize rather than snap to the right

Tags: windows-10

Pressing Win+Up snaps a (non-maximized) window to the right rather than maximizing it as was done with previous versions. It must be pressed multiple times to properly maximize the window. Is there a way to change this behavior or another convenient shortcut for maximizing a window? I know about Alt-Space, X, but that is far more inconvenient to use as it two actions rather than one.

Comment: Windows Up should still maximize, so something on your system is changed or broken if it does not. Is your monitor running in landscape or portrait orientation? Have you updated your video drivers? Have you checked this control's function on a different computer?

Answer (score 0):

Something has changed the default behaviour of <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>. Temporarily, [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) can help you remap keys to solve this.

```
LWin & Up::WinMaximise
```

However, you should explore why the default behaviour has changed and fix that. Try [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1091942/how-do-i-find-out-which-programs-have-registered-global-hotkeys-in-windows-10?rq=1) SuperUser question for solutions.