# Ctrl+L stopped clearing screen in PuTTY sessions

Tags: windows-10, ssh, terminal, putty

I have PuTTY 0.76 running on Windows 10 2004.

I use PuTTY for connecting to several Linux servers using SSH.

In past I have been able to to clear terminal screen with key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.
But now that combination has stopped working and only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> clears the terminal screen now.
This is same for all Linux servers I connect to and the servers have not changed so something must have changed in PuTTY settings or Windows.

How could I restore ability to clear screen with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>?

I have tried checking PuTTY settings but was not able to find anything related to this. I also tried searching information about Windows settings that could cause this but did not find anything.

Comment: Ctrl-L or `clear` will not clear the page. It will scroll till previous data disappears. You can still scroll backwards and view the buffer data.

Comment: With terminal emulators there is no standard I know that specifies bytes (byte sequences) for Ctrl+Shift+letter different than for Ctrl+letter. In general a terminal emulator can be configured to send different bytes (or byte sequences) but usually Ctrl+Shift+L generates `^L` (0x0C) like Ctrl+L does. My bet is some local software (if not your Windows itself) has registered a global hotkey. When you hit Ctrl+L PuTTY is not aware of it. Does this help? [How do I find out which programs have registered global hotkeys in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/q/1091942/432690)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Methods described in that post helped me to find program that had taken over `Ctrl+l`. Changin shortcut settings of the other program solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments I found out that another program had taken over keyboard shorcut for clearing the terminal screen.

I used methods descriped in [How do I find out which programs have registered global hotkeys in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1091942/how-do-i-find-out-which-programs-have-registered-global-hotkeys-in-windows-10) to find program that had taken over the key combination.

After I changed keyboard shortcut in the other program clearing terminal screen in Putty started working again with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.