# Find a custom keyboard shortcut in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, powershell, keyboard-shortcuts

On my corporate computer, a keyboard shortcut (R ALT + W) is assigned to open a powershell app.

I would like to deactivate this shortcut, because it's conflicting with my keyboard mapping.

Using process explorer, I could identify the command line involved :

```
powershell.exe -sta -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -file form.ps1
```

But I'm not able to find where the keyboard shortcut is defined.

Any idea to do this ?

Comment: Can you open the `form.ps1` file?  What is inside?

Comment: I guess you need to hunt for desktop shortcut files and see which one has that keyboard shortcut defined..

Comment: Here is an exhaustive answer: https://superuser.com/a/1096520/673426 . Since your hotkey starts a program, it's almost certainly a desktop shortcut with a hotkey defined, though it can be hiding elsewhere.